# Compiling graph-tool on RHEL

Tags: boost, compilation, configure, rhel, graph-tool

I need to use Python's graph-tool on a RHEL6 server.
The system administrator has not been able to install the boost library from a repository that he trusts (or whatever), so has installed it at

/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/

Inside are two directories, boost/ and libs/  which I am taking to be the header and libs directories.

I downloaded the source:

```
wget http://downloads.skewed.de/graph-tool/graph-tool-2.2.44.tar.bz2
```

And unpacking that, I tried:

```
env CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include' LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/' ./configure
```

but that didn't give any different result than "./configure" by itself.
It says:

> checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... configure: error: We could not
>   detect the boost libraries (version 1.53 or higher). If you have a
>   staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT
>   in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If
>   you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number
>   looking in . See http://randspringer.de/boost for
>   more documentation.

I also tried:

```
\env BOOST_ROOT='/usr/local/boost_1_59_0' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/boost' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/libs/'
./configure
```

but that got the same.

I also tried:

```
./configure  --with-boost-libdir=/usr/local/boost_1_59_0/libs/ --with-boost=/usr/local/boost_1_59_0
```

I obviously don't know what I'm doing.
Is this enough to see what I've done wrong?

Update:

gcc version:
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Looking at config.log from the graph-tool's failed configure, I find the following towards the end:

```
configure:17873: g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0  -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++0x -ftemplate-depth-250 -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -fvisibility=default -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unknown-pragmas  -I/usr/include/python2.6  conftest.cpp >&5
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0"
configure:17873: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2.44"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "graph-tool 2.2.44"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://graph-tool.skewed.de/tickets"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://graph-tool.skewed.de"
| #define PACKAGE "graph-tool"
| #define VERSION "2.2.44"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
| #define _ALL_SOURCE 1
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
| #define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| #define HAVE_PYTHON "2.6"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
|   #include <boost/version.hpp>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   #if BOOST_VERSION >= 105300
|   // Everything is okay
|   #else
|   #  error Boost version is too old
|   #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:17972: g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0  -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++0x -ftemplate-depth-250 -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -fvisibility=default -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unknown-pragmas  -I/usr/include/python2.6  -I/include/boost-0 conftest.cpp >&5
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0"
configure:17972: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2.44"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "graph-tool 2.2.44"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://graph-tool.skewed.de/tickets"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://graph-tool.skewed.de"
| #define PACKAGE "graph-tool"
| #define VERSION "2.2.44"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
| #define _ALL_SOURCE 1
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
| #define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| #define HAVE_PYTHON "2.6"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
|       #include <boost/version.hpp>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|       #if BOOST_VERSION >= 105300
|       // Everything is okay
|       #else
|       #  error Boost version is too old
|       #endif
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:17991: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.53 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
```

Comment: Take a look inside the ``config.log`` file, to see why the library is not being found.

Comment: It doesn't seem to tell me anything more than what I wrote above. There are plenty of other "error" lines, but these may be part of a normal configure? And don't appear to be related obviously to boost.

Comment: It certainly tells you the actual error that is generated when the test for boost is compiled. Look at the file from the end, searching for the last error.

Comment: What is your GCC version?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is stated in the website (https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download), you need GCC 4.8 or above to compile graph-tool, since it is written in C++11. GCC 4.4 is not supported.